# how is cat < file1.txt file2.txt interpreted?

Tags: shell, unix

I tried this command and it outputted file2.txt. Why does this happen? I am asking this question because I am writing a c shell, so maybe you know how to avoid this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as it is expected:

> The cat utility reads files sequentially, writing them to the standard
>   output.  The file operands are processed
>        in command-line order.  If file is a single dash (`-') or absent, cat reads from the standard input.

Create some demo files:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo this is d$i > d$i; done
```

the `cat d1` shows

```
this is d1
```

This is what do you expected - the `d1` is the `cat`'s argument . The `cat < d3` shows

```
this is d3
```

Again, it works as should - here isn't any argument, so the cat displays it's standard input. Then finally,

the `cat d1 - d3 < d2` shows

```
this is d1
this is d2
this is d3
```

E.g. the cat reads it's arguments, e.g. first the `d1` then found the `-` (as indicator for the `stdin` so displays the `d2` (because of `< d2`) and continues with `d3` as the last file in the arguments. Of course, the

```
cat - d1 d3 < d2
```

will show

```
this is d2
this is d1
this is d3
```

Every program has by default attached 3 file descriptors. The `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. What the program **doing** with them, (and how) it is fully in the given program responsibility. The `cat` is designed as it is described in the doc, e.g. it prints to `stdout` the files from his arguments (and opening them internally using `fopen` and reads the file content from the opened descriptor) and when finds the `-` (or has no argument) then reads the `stdin`. So the your question:

```
cat d1 < d2
```

will find the `d1` as argument, so the cat opens the file `d1` and prints it's content. And because here isn't the `-`, ignores the `stdin` fully and prints only

```
this is d1
```

Also note, the 3 default descriptors `std(in|out|err)` has attached to the process always. Even if the process is started **without** the shell. Let say from some daemon process, or from your program directly using `fork/exec`. The difference is: when it is started from shell, the shell has connected the all above descriptors to your terminal. So, when you going to run the `cat` the:

- shell `fork`s itself (e.g. here will be two identical processes and both runs side-by-side - the parent and the child. The **only** difference between two is the `PID`).
- the forked process has the same descriptors as the parent, e.g. they're connected to the terminal, or, if you doing some redirections in the shell the child process before the `exec` replaces it's standard descriptors with the descriptors from/to given files. (see the `dup(2)` system call)
- next, the child is replaced with the `cat` program (`exec`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a shell problem but due to the way `cat` behaves.

Either `cat`:

1. reads from standard input (if no file argument given)
2. reads from argument given files

but not both (in basic behavior). As you gave `file2.txt` as an argument `cat` only reads that file and just ignore its standard input (redirect from `file1.txt`).

There exists a special argument to enforce reading from standard input (`-`) that you must use to make `cat` takes in account the redirection.